# categorize ServiceStack methods

Tags: servicestack

Imagine I have two "areas" in my API, inventory and orders. I can quite easily group all methods related to inventory into "`/inventory/`" and to orders "`/orders/`" routes.

However, when I go to the root page of API where all methods are shown (`IndexOperations.html`) all methods are mixed together into one big list.

Is there any way to group methods from different areas on that list? For example show something like this on the operations index page.

```
Inventory
  Method1
  Method2

Orders
  Method1
  Method2
```

Comment: Hello any luck with this? I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Group your operations:

If you group your DTOs into a `static class` as shown below, then ordering will be taken care of automatically *assuming you want the groups alphabetically*.

```cs
public static class UserOperations
{
    [Route("/Users","POST")]
    public class CreateUserRequest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    ...
}

public static class DuckOperations
{
    [Route("/Ducks","POST")]
    public class CreateDuckRequest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    ...
}
```

## Alternatively specify the sort:

The ServiceStack `MetadataFeature` in v4.09+ provides access to the `IndexPageFilter` which lets you specify specify the `Sort` function that is applied to the index pages' `OperationNames`, where the OperationName is the full type name of the DTO.

```cs
var metadata = Plugins.First(x => x is MetadataFeature) as MetadataFeature;
// This is the default sort, replace with one that groups
metadata.IndexPageFilter = (page) => page.OperationNames.Sort((a,b) => b.CompareTo(a));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is this possible to do in Servicestack 3.9?

Comment: @Rasmus I don't believe that level of control is available in 3.9. For 3.9 the best metadata is really Swagger.